# R as.POSIXct try two input formats

Tags: r, date, format

I am reading in a .csv of dates and gps positions. I need to convert the date column to a date class. 
I am using:

```
data = data.frame(rbind(c('2016/07/19 17:52:00',3674.64416424279,354.266660979476), 
         c('2016/07/19 17:54:00',3674.65121597935,354.246972537617),
         c('2016/07/19 17:55:00',3674.65474186293,354.237128326737),
         c('2016/07/19 17:56:00',3674.65826775671,354.227284122559)))
colnames(data) = (c('GMT_DateTime','northing','easting'))

data$GMT_DateTime<-as.POSIXct(data$GMT_DateTime, tz="GMT", format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Sometimes the date in the .csv to be read is formatted as `"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"` and sometimes as `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"`

Is there a way to feed in two possible formats to as.POSIXct() to try both possible formats? I imagine something like this:

```
data$GMT_DateTime<-as.POSIXct(data$GMT_DateTime, tz="GMT", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M" or "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's a really, really bad idea to create a dataset like that. See what happens to each of your vectors: `c('2016/07/19 17:52:00',3674.64416424279,354.266660979476)` mixes a character string with numbers making *all of them* character strings. Then function `data.frame` default is `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`, one of the most dangerous defaults in R. To see why check out `str(data)`. All your variables are of class `factor`.

Comment: Hi Rui, Thanks for your input and resources. I was just trying to create a small example dataset to give context for my question. I am actually reading in a .csv created in another program using read.csv() so my numerical values are read in as numbers.

Comment: The `anytime` and/or `lubridate` packages maybe able to handle the arbitrary inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what follows I will use package `lubridate`.
I have added two extra rows to the example dataset, with date/time values in the `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"` format. Note that that column is of class `character`, if it is of class `factor` it will probably throw an error.
As for the *warnings*, don't worry, they are just `lubridate` telling you that it found several formats and cannot process them all in one go.

```
tmp <- data$GMT_DateTime    # work on a copy

na <- is.na(ymd_hms(tmp))
data$GMT_DateTime[!na] <- ymd_hms(tmp)[!na]
data$GMT_DateTime[na] <- mdy_hm(tmp)[na]
data$GMT_DateTime <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(data$GMT_DateTime),  
                                format = "%Y-%m-%d",  
                                origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")

rm(tmp)    # final clean up
```

**Data in dput() format.**

```
data <-
structure(list(GMT_DateTime = c("2016/07/19 17:52:00", "2016/07/19 17:54:00", 
"2016/07/19 17:55:00", "2016/07/19 17:56:00", "07/22/2016 17:02", 
"07/23/2016 17:15"), northing = c(3674.64416424279, 3674.65121597935, 
3674.65474186293, 3674.65826775671, 3674.662, 3674.665), easting = c(354.266660979476, 
354.246972537617, 354.237128326737, 354.227284122559, 354.2702, 
354.3123)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```